# Using retrained data with classify_image.py

Tags: tensorflow

I've been using tensorflow image recognition. I've build many scripts which interact with classify_image.py.

I also retrained the model using retrain.py, with my own dataset.

How can use the two files generated: output_graph.pb, output_labels.txt with classify_image.py ?

Comment: did you figure this out?  I'm at the same spot.  `C:\Users\Jason> python C:\Users\Jason\Repos\models\tutorials\image\imagenet\classify_image.py --model_dir=c:/tmp/ --image_file=c:/Users/Jason/Desktop/new_bad_example.jpg`  Even if I rename the `output_graph.pb` to `classify_image_graph_def.pb`, `output_labels.txt` to `imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt`, and copy over the incorrect but ?? `imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt`, `classify_image.py` overwrites them with its own download and gives answers only among the general imagenet labels, not my specialized ones.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, [the docs say](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)

> If you'd like to use the retrained model in a Python program [this example from @eldor4do shows what you'll need to do.](https://github.com/eldor4do/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/retraining-example.py)

Just copied/edited that one file locally, and `python .\edited-retraining-example.py`.  And that was easy.

Note that if you're on Windows, change all examples of `/tmp/...` to `c:/tmp/...`.